# sqlmap emulate Login Sequence for Webapplication

Tags: cookies, sql-injection, sqlmap

I hope this is the right place for my question

Is it possible to submit a login sequence with sqlmap for a web application that not provides a real session cookie.

In Webbrowser their is only a PHPSESSION ID and if i copy this to the --cookie parameter i get an redirect to the login page. so it is not possible to check for exploit because their is no valid session id.

Is there a way to "bypass" this Problem?

Comment: The session may be fingerprinted. Try to use the same user agent as the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem and cloned the whole header information logged with Firebug and used this as "Login".

This solved the Problem for me.